# Getting the y axis value(amplitude) on FFT

Tags: python

I am working on a FFT program, and I would like to get the frequency which has the largest amplitude or intensity in a sound. I checked out some codes on internet, but I couldn't find how to get the amplitude on a python program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `librosa.core.stft` This gives magnitude of each frequency bin at given time. More details here:

https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html?highlight=stft#librosa.core.stft

Comment: thanks! but can I change an wav file into a function which can be used in this stft??

Comment: yes, see `librosa.core.load`

Comment: wow, well,I can't understand the return value  of stft function. I thought there should be only two values, frequency and amplitude ,inside [], but There are so many values in it...